# Is there a way to automate a Webex chat whenever a GitHub merge is committed?

Tags: git, powershell, github, gitlab, webex

We have a GitHub repository where we great a pull request, make changes locally and then push that commit out to the master branch. After approvals — the master branch gets updated. After the local branch changes, approvals, and final commit — we must inform a Webex space about the changes and link the GitHub repo.

Is there a way to automate the Github repo link being automatically sent to the Webex space when triggered by the merge? Perhaps I can run a script from windows powershell that will send the Webex message?

I know how to create a Webex bot but I’m confused on how to integrate it to be triggered when the GitHub branch is merged